# Why does JBoss always redeploy .WAR files that have already been deployed but not changed?

Tags: java, jboss

I am new to using the JBoss 7.1.1 server and am confused by a behavior that I have observed.

My JBoss server is deploying the `six jBPM .war files (designer, drools-guvnor, jbpm-form-builder, jbpm-gwt-console, jbpm-gwt-console-server, jbpm-human-task-war)` which I have placed in the `.\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments` folder.

When I launched the server for the very first time it detected these files and deployed them.  I see the `deploymentNNN` and `tempNNN` folders appear in the `.\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs`  folder.  This is similar to the behavior I'm familiar with from my use of the tomcat server.

I then shut the server down and observe that the two folders created in `.\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs` are retained but their contents are automatically deleted.  When I restart the server it once again deploys the six jBPM files into a new pair of folders in `.\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs.`

This is very surprising because no changes have been made to the six jBPM files and the problem is that this redeployment takes 3 to 4 minutes.

If this was just happening in a "production" environment then perhaps this would not be much of an issue.  However, I am trying to integrate the JBoss server into use with Eclipse Kepler in a development environment and having to wait 3 to 4 minutes for each code change and server launch is not practical.

1) Can anyone explain why JBoss goes to the trouble to redeploy files that have not been changed?

2) Is this a behaviour that can be changed through a configuration setting?

3) Is there any settings where we can stop the jboss to redeploy the war files when it restarted

Thank you,
All

Answer (score 2):

In order to stop JBoss from re-deploying your apps (and deleting on shutdown),

try deploying the apps in unpacked form.

- extract the files to   `{name}.war directories`   `(e.g /designer.war, /drools-guvnor.war)`

  and then deploy these directories (i.e copy them to the deployments folder)

Alternatively, try to deploy them using the [JBoss CLI](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DeployAndUndeployWithTheCLI)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Extracting files to {name}.war directories avoids redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying differently won't change the fact that at startup JBOSS reloads your application to the JVM.

This can take time because your application stores data from database to your server memory. (You could as well be hitting [this WFLY-925 bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-925)... Or the one they are talking about [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202446?start=0)...)

The thing is **you normally don't need to restart your server completely when redeploying**. You can [hot-deploy your module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645751/is-it-possible-to-hot-deploy-jboss-module) - [see also full doc.](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment) at *Auto-deploy mode*. (make sure the [feature isn't disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212618/jboss-as-7-disable-hot-deployment)

If you need some [context to be reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969279/hot-deploy-on-jboss-how-do-i-make-jboss-see-the-change), I advise you have a specific procedure in your code that you can call to reload all cached info. instead of restarting completely (e.g. have a call to a specific URL from your application do it...)

Comment: 'Normally' is the keyword :)
I need to restart completely my JBoss, because it doesn't load all changes when doing a hot deploy on one of my modules. But another module may not have changes, so I don't want this module to redeploy always.

Comment: That's what I mean with "reloading some context". You must clearly identify what needs to be reloaded (data?), and have a specific function for this. Then you just call that function (specific url?, thread?) instead of restarting.