# Is it possible to hot deploy JBoss module

Tags: jboss

I have module deployed in jboss whenever changes happening module I need to restart the jboss to make changes effective. Is it possible to hot deploy JBoss module?

we are using JBOSS7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hot deploy on JBoss - how do I make JBoss "see" the change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969279/hot-deploy-on-jboss-how-do-i-make-jboss-see-the-change)

Comment: I guess above link is for war file hot deployment.. my requirement is module hot deployment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your IDE is Eclipse, consider using this plugin:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-hat-jboss-developer-studio